# How do I compile and install an individual object file with Automake?

Tags: c, makefile, autoconf, automake

I'm looking to build and install an object file (`crt1.o`, a C startup file) into the library directory (`/usr/lib`) with Automake and Autoconf.

So, my initial though about doing this was to create a `crt_DATA` variable inside the `Makefile.am` file, and define special targets on how to build the file. However, this idea has an issue: the file would be installed in a data directory instead of a library directory.

I then proceeded to try adding `crt1.o` to the `lib_LIBRARIES` section of my `Makefile.am` and creating `crt1_o_SOURCES`. However, this gave an error:

```
error: 'crt1.o' is not a standard library name
```

At this point, I could not think of any more possible ways to do this.

How do I compile and install an individual object file using Automake?

---

Very specific requirements:

- `crt1.o` **cannot** be built into its own shared library or archive. It has to be *just* an object file. It's mandated by the compiler to be this way, so I have my hands tied.
- It would be lovely if this file could be tracked and installed to the correct place if `DESTDIR` is changed.

Comment: @JL2210 I see you are providing your own standard C library.  That explains the need to install crt1.o.  That's a pretty interesting task.  You're on the right path.  Ignore my prior commentary about not providing crt1.o, unless you actually don't want to write your own glibc.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally an object file is not useful by itself.  I can't be run, and it can't be used except to link to other object files to make a program.

You probably want a "shared object" file, or a `.so` file, if you want to build a library.  Or, if you are keen to have the library statically linked, you might want a "library file", or a `.la` file.

Automake uses Libtool to build both kinds of library files, but it can get complicated.  That's because these library files are a bit different across multiple platforms, and automake/libtool attempts to handle the platform differences for you.

Assuming that the above information isn't what you need, and you really want to install the `.o` file, then you should add the following to your `Makefile.am`

```
somethingdir = /path/to/where/you/want/the/file
something_DATA = the_file.o
```

This treats the object file as a data file, and installs the data file at the chosen path.

Again, I'm nearly certain that this is not what you really need, but at least you do know how to install an object file.

What you probably need is one of:

1. Build the object file into an executable, and install that executable
2. Build the object file into a shared object library, and install that library
3. Build the object file into a library archive (that's an .la file), and install that library archive.

as plain object files, `.o` files, cannot easily be used without the required header files used to build them, and often the Makefiles and build system used to build them too.

Comment: The information above "Assuming that the above information isn't what you need" isn't what I need. See the edit to my question.

Comment: @JL2210 Well, I gave you the instructions on how to install it, even though I have my doubts as to how useful it might be.  So, you can install it that way if you want, and if that's really what you need, you have your solution above.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. (As a side note, the file is required by the C compiler, so I have my hands tied.)

Comment: @JL2210 Yes, all `.o` files are required by the C compiler, or actually by the linker, which is often called by the C compiler.  I assure you, your hands are not as tied as you think.  Odds are you need to include the source differently, using `bin_PROGRAMS` and `programName_SOURCES` instead of installing the `.o` file.  At least look into those items to see if you're walking down the wrong paths.

Comment: Just to clarify: This *specific* file is required at this *specific* location by the C compiler. I'm just following glibc, musl, gcc, and all the other compilers/standard C libs out there.

Comment: My hands are *definitely* as tied as I think. This file serves no purpose other than to be linked into every program that runs on my system by the compiler. It would be totally useless otherwise.

Comment: @JL2210 Oh, I do know what crt1.o is, but if you're using glibc, then you aren't supposed to provide it.  It's provide by glibc, and that's why I think installing it is a mistake.  That's why I don't think your hands are as tied as you think.  I've only been programming in C for about 30 years now, and I still haven't had a need to install my own copy of it.  Odds are you're on the wrong path.  But still, good luck!

Comment: Well, let's just say that I'm [writing my own glibc](https://github.com/JL2210/minilibc). I may or may not be on the wrong path, but it's still a challenging exercise to be writing my own standard C library.

Comment: @JL2210 Well, if that's the goal, you're on the right path.  Even if you don't finish the exercise, I'm sure you'll learn a lot.  Good luck!

Comment: I shouldn't say exercise. More of a hobby that I try to complete in my spare time. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is this:

```
crtdir = $(libdir)
crt_DATA = crt1.o Scrt1.o crti.o crtn.o

crt1.o: $(top_srcdir)/src/crt/crt1.c
        $(CC) -c -fno-PIC $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

Scrt1.o: $(top_srcdir)/src/crt/crt1.c
        $(CC) -c -fPIC $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

crti.o: $(top_srcdir)/arch/$(ARCH)/src/crt/crti.s
        $(CCAS) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

crtn.o: $(top_srcdir)/arch/$(ARCH)/src/crt/crtn.s
        $(CCAS) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Of course, the tabs and spaces are messed up, but still.

Credit to @EdwinBuck for his answer, the inspiration for mine!